# Starting discord.py command cooldown only if condition is met

Tags: python, discord.py

I want the cooldown of one of my commands to start only if a condition in the function is met, like so:

```py
@bot.command
async def move(ctx, destination):
    destinations=["d1", "d2", "d3"] # List of valid arguments for the command
    if destination in destinations:
        movement(destination) # Function to actually move, not important for the question
        # Start cooldown only here
    else:
        await ctx.send("This is not a valid destination")
```

This way, if the user mistypes the destination, they won't be penalized with the cooldown. How can i achieve that?

EDIT1: one would normally use discord.py's built-in @commands.cooldown decorator, here is the source:

```py
def cooldown(rate, per, type=BucketType.default):
    def decorator(func):
        if isinstance(func, Command):
            func._buckets = CooldownMapping(Cooldown(rate, per, type))
        else:
            func.__commands_cooldown__ = Cooldown(rate, per, type)
        return func
    return decorator
```

However this applies to the whole command.(It is normally placed after the @bot.command decorator)

Comment: How do you handle cooldown? Do you use a function?

Comment: @ImranD edited the message to include the source for the cooldown decorator, more information about its elements are in the discord.py documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a lots of ways to craft your own cooldowns, here is a simple one that can do the trick. The idea behind it is for the bot to "remember" the last time someone used this specific command and to check this time before allowing the player to move.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta    

on_cooldown = {} # Dictionary with user IDs as keys and datetime as values
destinations=["d1", "d2", "d3"] # List of valid arguments for the command
move_cooldown = 5 # cooldown of the move command in seconds

@bot.command()
async def move(ctx, destination):

    if destination in destinations:
        author = ctx.author.id

        try:
            # calculate the amount of time since the last (successful) use of the command
            last_move = datetime.now() - on_cooldown[author] 
        except KeyError:
            # the key doesn't exist, the player used the command for the first time
            # or the bot has been shut down since
            last_move = None
            on_cooldown[author] = datetime.now()

        if last_move is None or last_move.seconds > move_cooldown:
            # move(...)
            on_cooldown[author] = datetime.now() # the player successfully moved so we start his cooldown again
            await ctx.send("You moved!")
        else:
            await ctx.send("You're still on cooldown.")    

    else:
        await ctx.send("This is not a valid destination")
```

Note : you may or may not need to remove the parentheses after the `@bot.command` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this is what you're looking for, but there's a way to make the cooldown only activate after the code parses properly with this bit of code:

```
@bot.command(cooldown_after_parsing=True)
@commands.cooldown(rate, per, type=<BucketType.default: 0>)
```

you can find the document for commands.cooldown [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown)

and the doc for cooldown_after_parsing [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.Command.cooldown_after_parsing)