# How to add cooldown function to discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I have this cooldown decorator for discord.py for a shared cooldown! Here it is:

```
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

on_cooldown = {}  # A dictionary mapping user IDs to cooldown ends


def cooldown(seconds):
    def predicate(context):
        if (cooldown_end := on_cooldown.get(context.author.id)) is None or cooldown_end < datetime.datetime.now():  # If there's no cooldown or it's over
            if context.valid and context.invoked_with in (*context.command.aliases, context.command.name):  # If the command is being run as itself (not by help, which runs checks and would end up creating more cooldowns if this didn't exist)
                on_cooldown[context.author.id] = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)  # Add the datetime of the cooldown's end to the dictionary
            return True  # And allow the command to run
        else:
            raise commands.CommandOnCooldown(commands.BucketType.user, (cooldown_end - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds)  # Otherwise, raise the cooldown error to say the command is on cooldown

    return commands.check(predicate)
```

I wanted to add the cooldown function to it and wasn't sure how to!
BTW For anyone looking to make shared cooldown for their discord.py bots, here it is :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting discord.py command cooldown only if condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285467/starting-discord-py-command-cooldown-only-if-condition-is-met)  

It is not using a decorator but the principle is the same.

Comment: @vgalin That kinda did help me out, but I am struggling to understand whether I could add a reset cooldown command to this function.